# How to rewrite deprecated jQuery bind() function?

Tags: jquery, deprecated

jQuery's `bind()` is deprecated. How can I rewrite the jQuery bind in this code?

```
// HACK check async to allow time to bind listeners
setTimeout(function() {
  this.check();
}.bind(this));
```

Thank you

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated in jQuery, but the example code you're using there has nothing to do with jQuery. It's using the native `function.bind()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Even if it was jQuery's [`.bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/), then the answer would be available in the official documentation for that method -> [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: hmmm then i get a wrong warning from jquery migrate on that code.  Using wp 5.7 with debug_script="true" 

I got this warning on the imagesLoaded script https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/



Thanks

Comment: @Andreas  I am aware of the documentation and i have read it before submitting the question in here. I was hoping for a answer to my question not being thrown back at the jquery docs. As that was where i started and could not figure out the solution. Thanks anyway